# A JS array or hidden divs to store questions/flashcards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html

I'm making a website that displays questions/flashcards. First, I load a set of flashcards from the server (originally I was thinking about loading every flashcard separately, but this requires too many MySQL queries) and then a user can view them one by one. There might be for example 30 or even 300 flashcards. I load them in a separate div and using css display I only display the first one from the stack, whereas other flashcards are hidden. Then it is possible to move the flashcard to the end or remove from the stack with jQuery. I wonder, would it be better to store the flashcards in a javascript array instead and then for example print the first element of an array that would contain the first flashcard? Which practice would you find better / faster? Or they both are equally good?

Comment: 300 cards is nothing. I doubt you will see any performance boost. But using AJAX and loading each card when it is needed might be a good idea too.

Comment: Are you creating the divs using backend code then handling them with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, you'd have to benchmark the different approaches to say for certain because there are a number of variables that can have hard-to-predict effects.  And depending on the situation, it might not be worth the trouble.  Here are some some basic considerations:

- If there is no upper limit to the number of flashcards you may have to support, consider going with the AJAX-loading-one-at-a-time approach.  The issue of it being too many MySQL queries on the backend may be something to fix either with MySQL tuning or caching query results on the backend.
- If you are targeting a specific device or OS or browser, then test performance on that device or OS or browser.  A mobile phone may not perform well with a large JavaScript array and many DOM manipulations, or the non-AJAX solutions may take too long to load over a slow network, or if there are images and whatnot involved you may hit a document size limit, for example.  I'm making these up, though.  You'd need to actually test.
- If there is a known upper limit to the number of flash cards and it is reasonably small, then the load-it-all-at-once techniques you are considering may be more attractive.  I once did a silly quiz application with 10 questions and didn't bother with AJAX for it because the size of the quiz was so small.  (I wrote it so I could easily drop in an AJAX-y approach should the requirements there change, but they never did.)
- Consider the real possibility that it doesn't matter--that the difference in performance will be so small that you should just do what will work for you.  This is not the case if the site needs to scale up to a million simultaneous users.  But if it's for a single class of 15 people or something, well, you might not want to spend a whole lot of time benchmarking.  (I guess this is the closest to an actual answer to the specific question you pose.)